# Spring cloud Stream Kafka DLQ throw RecordTooLargeException for Batch mode

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using Spring cloud Stream kafka Binder in my project. We have enabled the batch-mode true and batch size is 500 messages. We are using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer to send the message to DLQ. If any message failed then we throw BatchListenerFailedException. This
functionality worked fine and messages are sending into DLQ.

Recently we have an issue where while sending the message to DLQ, Kafka throws **"RecordTooLargeException: Message is 15762601 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576"**. Our individual message size is in bytes.  What I observed is Kafka read the messages in batch which is 500 messages and if any 1 message failed, Kafka wrap all the 500 messages with exceptions and put it into Kafka Header in "kafka_dlt-exception-message" and "kafka_dlt-exception-stacktrace". And due this message size grows further.

I can remove those 2 headers("kafka_dlt-exception-message" and "kafka_dlt-exception-stacktrace") to get rid of this issue but my question is, Is this a right way to handle this issue?

Below is the error stack trace I am getting. I am using Spring cloud stream version **3.2.6**.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@2a4bc0e4]; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.BatchListenerFailedException: Exception while generating outbound message; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[{"message":{src:"test"}}, {"message":{src:"test1"}}, {"message":{src:"test2"}}, headers={skip-input-typeconversion=false,kafka_offset=[2193, 2194, 2195],kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@4730c07,  kafka_conversionFailures=[], kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[2, 2, 2], kafka_receivedMessageKey=[test, test1, test2], kafka_batchConvertedHeaders=[{}, {}, {}], kafka_receivedTopic=[input-topic, input-topic, input-topic], kafka_receivedTimestamp=[1677649913630, 1677649913629,1677649913629], contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=group1}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
```

Below is consumer function

```
@Bean
    Consumer<Message<String>> processMessages() {
        return input -> {
        try{
            //Processing Logic
            }catch(CustomException exp){
            throw new BatchListenerFailedException(exp.getMessage(),exp.getCause(),exp.getIndex()) //getIndex() return the index of the message
        }
        };
    }
```

After debugging the issue I Observed that method **AbstractMessageHandler -> handleMessage** inside the exception block, code is passing all the messages to MessageHandlingException class which I thought it should be passing only failed message(I may be wrong) and due to that the header "kafka_dlt-exception-message" and "kafka_dlt_exception-stacktrace" contains all the messages and the message size grows.

Thanks

Comment: Your work around is correct, but the exception message should not contain the whole batch, just the failed record; please edit the question to show an example. I need to determine if it's a bug in spring-kafka or spring-cloud-stream.

Comment: Is it possible that you are adding the `batch.toString()` to the exception's message?

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected; the stack trace is as it should be; please edit the question to show your code/config so we can see what's wrong...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75594534Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75594534Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<List<String>> consumer() {
        return list -> {
            System.out.println(list);
            if (list.size() > 1) {
                throw new BatchListenerFailedException("test", 1);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic dlt() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("consumer-in-0.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> cust(
            KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {

        return (container, group, dest) -> {
            container.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template) {

                @Override
                protected void publish(ProducerRecord<Object, Object> outRecord,
                                       KafkaOperations<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> inRecord) {

                    super.publish(outRecord, kafkaTemplate, inRecord);
                    System.out.println("DLT Stack Trace: \n" +
                            new String(outRecord.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE).value()));
                }


            }, new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
        };

    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("consumer-in-0", "test1".getBytes());
            template.send("consumer-in-0", "test2".getBytes());
            template.send("consumer-in-0", "test3".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer-in-0.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer-in-0.consumer.batch-mode=true

spring.kafka.producer.properties.linger.ms=1000
```

Result:

```
[test1, test2, test3]
DLT Stack Trace: 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2945)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2487)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2463)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2402)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2294)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2187)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2166)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1524)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@1587fead], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[[B@7f544fe8, [B@7e09af6, [B@281b074c], headers={kafka_offset=[15, 16, 17], kafka_conversionFailures=[], kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7314418f, kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[0, 0, 0], kafka_receivedMessageKey=[null, null, null], kafka_batchConvertedHeaders=[{}, {}, {}], kafka_receivedTopic=[consumer-in-0, consumer-in-0, consumer-in-0], kafka_receivedTimestamp=[1677603279132, 1677603279140, 1677603279140], contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=foo}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:327)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.lambda$sendMessage$1(MessageProducerSupport.java:262)
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:492)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:394)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationBatchMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:568)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationBatchMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:540)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2473)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.BatchListenerFailedException: test @-1
    at com.example.demo.So75594534Application.lambda$consumer$0(So75594534Application.java:37)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:973)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:684)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:533)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:785)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:621)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    ... 29 more
```

There's nothing in the stack trace about the batch.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I am not adding batch.toString() in Exception message. If I see the stack trace message you shared it has all 3 payloads. I hope I have read it correctly. `[org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@1587fead], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[[B@7f544fe8, [B@7e09af6, [B@281b074c], headers={kafka_offset=[15, 16, 17], kafka_conversionFailures=[], kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7314418f, kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[0, 0, 0]

Comment: That doesn't help; I need to see the complete stack trace (you can omit most of the failedMessage content to reduce the size, but include the start of it). Edit the question; also show your function and exactly what version of Spring Cloud Stream that you are using.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have updated the question with the details you have asked. But isnt the "failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload" inside the stack trace header contains only the failed message payload and not all the payloads?

Comment: You are still not showing the full stack trace, but the problem is with the `nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`; which includes the failedMessage - when you throw the BatchListenerFailedException, don't add the cause. In version 4.0 (which uses Spring 6), the nested exception is not shown in the message.

Comment: I tried removing cause from BatchListenerFailedException but still same issue. ```throw new BatchListenerFailedException(exp.getMessage(),exp.getIndex())``` It only cutdown the stack trace little bit. I still see all the messages in the batch into header "kafka_dlt-exception-message" and "kafka_dlt_exception-stacktrace" of the failed message.

Comment: You need to post a complete stack trace somewhere like paste in or a GitHub gist, so that I can see why it is so large.